# How do I make so that when I input a value into a scanner if it is not an integer it won't give me an error?

Tags: java.util.scanner, parseint

I am writing a program that does simple math problems. What I am trying to do is to make it so that even if I input a string into the the scanner level it will not give me an error. The level is to choose the difficulty of the math problems. I have tried parseInt, but am at a loss of what to do now.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test { 
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Random generator = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String level = intro();//This method intorduces the program,
        questions(level);//This does the actual computation.
    }
    public static String intro() {

        System.out.println("HI - I am your friendly arithmetic tutor.");
        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("What level do you choose? ");
        String level = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("OK " + name + ", here are ten exercises for you at the level " + level + ".");
        System.out.println("Good luck.");
        return level;
    }
    public static void questions(String level) {
        int value = 0, random1 = 0, random2 = 0;
        int r = 0, score = 0;
        int x = Integer.parseInt("level");
        if (x==1) {
            r = 4;          
        }       
        else if(x==2) {
            r = 9; 
        }
        else if(x==3) {
            r = 50; 
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            random1 = generator.nextInt(r);//first random number.
            random2 = generator.nextInt(r);//second random number.
            System.out.print(random1 + " + " + random2 + " = ");
            int ans = keyboard.nextInt();
            if((random1 + random2)== ans) {
                System.out.println("Your answer is correct!");
                score+=1;
            }
            else if ((random1 + random2)!= ans) {
            System.out.println("Your answer is wrong!");
            }
        }
        if (score==10 || score==9) {
            if (score==10 && x == 3) {
                System.out.println("This system is of no further use.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Choose a higher difficulty");
            }
            System.out.println("You got " + score + " out or 10");
        }
        else if (score<=8 && score>=6) {
            System.out.println("You got " + score + " out or 10");
            System.out.println("Do the test again");
        }
        else if (score>6) {
            System.out.println("You got " + score + " out or 10");
            System.out.println("Come back for extra lessons");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error I see is that you tried to `Integer.parseInt()` a *String* "level" instead of the *String variable* named level

```
    int x = Integer.parseInt("level");
```

should be

```
    int x = Integer.parseInt(level);
```

Also, when defining level you can use `keyboard.nextInt` instead of `keyboard.nextLine`

```
String level = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Then, you wouldn't have to do an `Integer.parseInt()` operation later on